# Users with "Contribute" access cannot edit document attached to a SharePoint 2010 Discussion Board post

Tags: 2010, permissions, discussion-board

Users on my 2010 site can't edit a document attached to a discussion board post even though they have "Contribute" access. Users with "Full Control" can, of course, but users with Contribute cannot.

This seem to be an issue with the discussion board web part itself, because those users with "Contribute" access *can* edit documents in a Document Library.

How can I set up the Discussion Board to enable "Contribute"-level users the permission to edit documents?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I am having a similar problem to you however mine is on a Sharepoint 2013 setup. Do you have any idea how to give contributors in my discussion board access to upload documents and attach pictures to their posts?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Discussion Board settings and go into the Advanced settings.  Change the Item-Level permissions for Create and Edit access to Create and Edit all items.